# Trying to add icon to right side of button on screen - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am building a settings UI screen for this app, and I am trying to add this icon arrow to the right side of the button, but no matter what I do will not work. I have tried marginLeft, flexDirection, position, etc and they all don't seem to change where the icon is. The only thing that works is if I do right: 150 or some other number, but I don't want to be doing that through each button as I want them to all line up.

So far this is what my code looks like:

```
<View style={styles.container} className='px-6>
       <View className="w-full" style={styles.ButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(RouteName.home)} className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-3 w-24">
            <Ionicons name='person-sharp' size={20} color="grey"></Ionicons>
            <Text>Profile</Text>
            <AntDesign name='right' size={20} color='#7A7A7A' style={{left: 223}}></AntDesign>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View className="w-full mt-4 mb-7" style={styles.MiddleButton}>
          <TouchableOpacity className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-3">
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='bell' size={24} color='grey'></MaterialCommunityIcons>
            <Text>Notification Settings</Text>
            <AntDesign name='right' size={20} color='#7A7A7A' style={{left: 128}}></AntDesign>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View className="w-full" style={{paddingLeft: 15, display: 'block'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-3">
            <AntDesign name='cloudupload' size={24} color="grey"></AntDesign>
            <Text>Backup WRKR</Text>
            <AntDesign name='right' size={20} color='#7A7A7A' style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}></AntDesign>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
</View>
```

And my Styles look like this:

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'left',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
TextContainer: {
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderColor: '#DADEE8',
  borderWidth: .5,
  backgroundColor: '#FCFBFF',
  padding: 15
},
ButtonContainer: {
  paddingLeft: 15,
  paddingTop: 15
},
MiddleButton: {
  paddingLeft: 15,
  paddingTop: 15,
  paddingBottom: 15,
  borderBottomColor: '#DADEE8',
  borderBottomWidth: .5,
  borderTopColor: '#DADEE8',
  borderTopWidth: .5
}
```

I am supposed to have it look like this:
[image]

But so far it looks like this:
[image]

Don't judge the organization, I am very new to react-native so I am learning as I go! Also I was only able to get the icons to the right by using right: *a number* I am hoping there is an easier way to do it instead of guessing.

Comment: You need justifyContent: 'space-between'

Answer (score 0):

try this code in side type to return

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',marginEnd:10}}>
          <Image></Image>
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginEnd : 20}}>
          <Image/>
        </View>
      </View>
```